# Org Mode - Live Preview and Mathematics

Tags: org-mode, mathjax, math

I write a lot of documents using Markdown in VS Code and it is convenient because you have live preview capabilities and also live preview math formulae, using, if I am not mistaken, KaTeX, and without needing to run any command or press any keys. The part about math preview is especially important because as I have seen other solutions may need to have LaTeX installed.

As I already use Org Mode as a calendar I would prefer to be able to write documents in it, as I do in VS Code, but I haven't found any solution for the previewing, and especially for the math formulae without needing to install LaTeX and without needing to press keys every time. Is there any?

Comment: No: LaTeX is an absolute prerequisite.

Comment: @NickD All already existing solutions I know of work with LaTeX. Nevertheless, it seems possible to [make MathJaX work as standalone application](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10514/114571) and Emacs can render [SVG (if the lib is provided)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Image-Formats.html). Therefore, rendering LaTeX formulae without LaTeX should be possible in principle. The actual question is whether it makes sense.